# Eclipse An Error has occurred.See the log File (Windows x64)

Tags: java, eclipse

I am getting An Error has occurred.See the log File. I tried Installing Eclipse again but same problem every time. Even after installing JDK again it shows same Error.

### Heading ##> !SESSION 2018-11-01 19:21:55.728

> ----------------------------------------------- eclipse.buildId=4.9.0.I20180906-0745 java.version=1.8.0_191
>   java.vendor=Oracle Corporation BootLoader constants: OS=win32,
>   ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US Framework arguments:  -product
>   org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product Command-line arguments:  -os win32
>   -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-11-01 19:22:23.425 !MESSAGE
>   Application error !STACK 1 java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.getMessageCount(Display.java:2029)    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.foregroundIdleProc(Display.java:1317)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.VtblCall(Native Method)    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.init(Display.java:2711)   at
>   org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.(Device.java:144)   at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.(Display.java:472)  at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.(Display.java:463)  at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createDisplay(Workbench.java:749)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createDisplay(PlatformUI.java:163)     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.createDisplay(IDEApplication.java:185)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:128)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:199)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:391)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:246)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:595)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1501)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1474)

Comment: If your Java 8 is 64 bit and you have Eclipse installed in a new directory, I would guess that the download is broken.

Comment: I just started getting a very similar crash, different line number though.  I opened a bug report, https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=540762

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get eclipse to start out of pure dumb luck.  I held down the ctrl key while I clicked the eclipse icon in my taskbar.  I took the gamble of shutting down eclipse to see if I could repeat the fix.  Without holding down the ctrl key, no good.  But holding it down again got it to start.  I have no explanation.

I am running the latest Win10 build from the fast ring, build 18272.  So my issue and fix may or may not work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the bug already fixed in the development branch: Eclipse IBuilds(I20181114-1345 and onward - http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads

Anyway if you don't like to update to an unstable version you can use "Compatible wizard". I managed it by running the wizard (from context menu by right click) and select the following options: "Troubleshoot program" -> "The program worked in early version..." -> "I don't know".

Answer (score -1):

Not able to comment on the post above due to not having accrued enough Stack Overflow rep, however, I can attest that the above fix of holding CTRL key when launching Eclipse did work for me on Windows 18277.1000 (version 1809), Insiders Fast. Previously, using the command eclipse.exe -clean -clearPersistedState had worked as well, but stopped working as of about 11/10/2018. Might or might not be related to the latest Insiders preview update but is coincident with its installation.